# PostgreSQL IF NOT EXISTS return expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to check if a record doesn't exist in a table, using IF NOT EXISTS. If that record doesn't exist in the table, then return the following:

| Success | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 'No ID exists' |

I have this code so far:

```
do $$
declare 
begin 
    if not exists (Select 1 from user.permission where permission_id = 1) then 
    0 as Success, 'No ID exists' as message;
    end if;
end $$
```

And I'm getting the an error of "ERROR: syntax error at or near "0""

I'm using an IF statement because I only want to return anything if the record doesn't exist, else it moves onto the next query in my file (i.e. I don't want it returning NULL if the conditions are not met)

Comment: This seems like a better use for `case`; also, what do you want to return if the opposite is true?

Comment: @ps2goat It doesn't need to return anything if there is a match in the table, just needs to move onto the next query (not included in this post)

Comment: Is this a function/stored procedure or just a standard script?

Comment: @ps2goat a standard script

Answer (score 0):

Adding in the `THEN` statement `RETURN SELECT` if your plpgsql function returns a single record or `RETURN QUERY SELECT` if your plpgsql function returns a set of records may be usefull, see the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

```
create or replace your_function(your_list_of_parameters)
returns record language plpgsql as
$$
declare 
begin 
    if not exists (Select 1 from user.permission where permission_id = 1) then 
    return select 0 as Success, 'No ID exists' as message;
    end if;
end ; $$

create or replace your_function(your_list_of_parameters)
returns setof record language plpgsql as
$$
declare 
begin 
    if not exists (Select 1 from user.permission where permission_id = 1) then 
    return query select 0 as Success, 'No ID exists' as message;
    end if;
end ; $$
```